# Unfounded multiple downvotes and close requests

Tags: support, specific-question, closing, down-votes

I have asked [a quite legitimate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539004/pointfree-way-to-describe-binary-relations).

After a day I myself given an answer.

Without any reason both the question and the answer were voted down and there are close and delete requests.

I do not understand the reason for downvoting. It is annoying that they vote down a good question.

Is there anything I can do in such situation?

Comment: I just took a look.  I profess to not know much about the subject matter.  Despite that, what I do see is an argument between yourself and another user.  Rather than address the concerns of the other user, you simply stamp your foot and argue louder.  If you are being misunderstood, then it is wiser to understand why you are being misunderstood and perhaps spend time making your question clearer instead of assuming that the other users are simply ignorant.

Comment: Well, ironically, you will get more information once one more user votes to close your question. I guess the reason is "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: @JohnMa I can confirm that all 4 close votes were with the reason "unclear what you are asking". (As can see anybody with close-voting privilege, simply by clicking on close.) porton: If  this meta post is about this particular post, then it should be tagged ([tag:specific-question]). Since you did not use the tag, I suppose you added link to this question just as an illustration and you want discuss some more general issue. (Although it is not entirely clear what exactly you want to ask here on meta.)

Comment: Possibly also related to [this disturbing trend.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/22010/242)

Comment: While I agree that the post is a bit unclear, I think the treatment it received is unnecessarily harsh.  The first time I read it I didn't understand exactly what it was saying, but after rereading a few times I figured it out.  I would like to edit it to be clearer and get the question reopened, but unfortunately it has been deleted, so the most I can do for now is vote to undelete it.

Comment: @EricWofsey It is now undeleted

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt: Thank you for notifying me!

Answer (score 19):

A reason *was* given: people found your post unclear.

To fix? Learn to write more clearly. For example, compare your formulation of "pseudorelational semigroup" with, say, how textbooks formulate the notion of "group" or "vector space".

Assuming you have coherent ideas, you are probably suffering from the problem that you have lots of details in your head that you aren't writing down, and are having trouble recognizing that the details are missing because you know the details and mentally fill them in when you read your writings.

---

Additionally, "link-only posts" — posts that have some (or especially all) of their essential content on another website — are *strongly* discouraged.